# What does EOleSysError Unspecified Error at runtime with SysMon.ocx ActiveX control in delphi 2007 mean?

Tags: delphi, activex, perfmon

I found a really enticing sample of creating a Performance Monitor like feature using the SysMon.ocx ActiveX control that is included with windows.

I found a sample of using it within an HTML page that dynamically has added several performance counters (in this case, for SQL server performance).  Since Delphi can create ActiveX/OLE objects easily at runtime, I figured I would try to translate the HTML sample [here](https://gist.github.com/3239139) to Delphi.  The first step would be to import the Type Library and create a `SystemMonitor_TLB.pas`, which I created, via the usual way of importing it, using Delphi 2007.

I have registered the OCX, and imported the "System Monitor" OCX (SysMon.ocx) using the type library importer, which created an import TLB.pas file that looks like this. (Only a representative sample of the file is shown here).

```
unit SystemMonitor_TLB;

// ************************************************************************ //
// WARNING                                                                    
// -------                                                                    
// ...
// Type Lib: C:\Windows\system32\sysmon.ocx (1)
// LIBID: {1B773E42-2509-11CF-942F-008029004347}
// LCID: 0
// Helpfile: 
// HelpString: System Monitor Control
// DepndLst: 
//   (1) v2.0 stdole, (C:\Windows\system32\stdole2.tlb)
// Errors:
//   Hint: TypeInfo 'SystemMonitor' changed to 'SystemMonitor_'
//   Error creating palette bitmap of (TSystemMonitor_) 
// : Registry key CLSID\{C4D2D8E0-D1DD-11CE-940F-008029004347}\ToolboxBitmap32 not found
// ************************************************************************ //
// *************************************************************************//

{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF} // Unit must be compiled without type-checked pointers. 
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
{$VARPROPSETTER ON}
interface

uses Windows, ActiveX, Classes, Graphics, OleCtrls, OleServer, StdVCL, Variants;



// *********************************************************************//
// GUIDS declared in the TypeLibrary. Following prefixes are used:        
//   Type Libraries     : LIBID_xxxx                                      
//   CoClasses          : CLASS_xxxx                                      
//   DISPInterfaces     : DIID_xxxx                                       
//   Non-DISP interfaces: IID_xxxx                                        
// *********************************************************************//
const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  SystemMonitorMajorVersion = 3;
  SystemMonitorMinorVersion = 7;

  LIBID_SystemMonitor: TGUID = '{1B773E42-2509-11CF-942F-008029004347}';
  IID_...  // about 20 more lines of GUIDs s
// --SNIP--
// about 5000  lines of pretty typical import-TLB-code snipped
// --SNIP--
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents(dtlOcxPage, [TSystemMonitor_, TCounterItem, TLogFileItem]);
  RegisterComponents(dtlServerPage, [TCounters, TLogFiles, TCounterItem2, TSystemMonitor2, 
    TAppearPropPage, TGeneralPropPage, TGraphPropPage, TSourcePropPage, TCounterPropPage]);
end;

end.
```

The entire file above can be found as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/3239139).

I installed the package .dpk containing this unit, and created a demo form, and the ActiveX control seems to work, at least at designtime. When I run my demo app, If-and-only-if I added the component to the form, at designtime, I get an exception at runtime at the point where it seems to be part way through instantiating the base class `TOleControl`:

```
procedure TOleControl.CreateControl;
var
  Stream: IStream;
  CS: IOleClientSite;
  X: Integer;
begin
   //  about 12 lines not shown.
   OleCheck(FPersistStream.Load(Stream)); // here's where we get the mystery OLE error.
   DestroyStorage;
   // more code here.
end;
```

What I would like to know is:

1. What does the mystery OLE error mean, and does anyone know how I can fix it?
2. Alternatively, does anyone know how to work around the above, or otherwise get a working (at designtime and runtime) version of PerfMon's sysmon.ocx that works with delphi 2007 or xe2?
3. Is the hint in the comment some kind of key for solving this issue:

   ```
    //   Hint: TypeInfo 'SystemMonitor' changed to 'SystemMonitor_'
   ```

Update:  Note that I am talking about workarounds for design-time support.  It works fine when I only create the control at runtime, instead of designtime:

```
type
  TSystemMonitor = TSystemMonitor_;
...
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SysMonCtrl := TSystemMonitor.Create(Self);
 SysMonCtrl.Align := alClient;
 SysMonCtrl.Parent := Self;
 SysMonCtrl.Show;
end;
```

Maybe I should be doing it that way?

Comment: The ActiveX seems working at design time in Delphi 7, 2006 and 2009. I can place a `SystemMonitor` control on a form and *play* with it. I tested it under Windows XP 32-bit using auto-generated files via Import ActiveX (not using the one from *gist*). However, of all 5 components, only `SystemMonitor` is usable. The remaining components fails to be placed on a form and give a *Class not registered.* error. I already tried unregistering then registering the OCX, but still same problem. --- So, you might want to try importing the ActiveX yourself instead of using the ones from *gist*.

Comment: The GIST IS me importing the ActiveX myself.  If your ActiveX import differs from mine, please send me the diff.

Comment: Here are the ones for [Delphi 2006](http://pastebin.com/zhFUkfpC) and [Delphi 2009](http://pastebin.com/zfRyEdi6) (pastebin links). Note that they are imported from Windows XP, so it's an older *System Monitor* ActiveX version (less interface members). If the ActiveX in Windows 7 is backward compatible, those source codes should still be usable.